# NSCollectionView Drag & Drop using a File Promise

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I want to drag & drop one or multiple images from a `NSCollectionView` in my macOS application to a destination on the computer or into the photos app.

I am using a `NSFilePromiseProvider` because the the images are on my Android device and only thumbnails are displayed in my app. I want to pull the images to my computer after the drag completes.

## NSCollectionViewDelegate

```
extension ImageViewController: NSCollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, canDragItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>, with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, pasteboardWriterForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
        // Return a File Promise Provider as Pasteboard Writing.
        let provider = NSFilePromiseProvider(fileType: kUTTypeJPEG as String, delegate: self)
        provider.userInfo = meta[indexPath.item] // Some data to identify the dragged image
        return provider
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, validateDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, proposedIndexPath proposedDropIndexPath: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSIndexPath>,
        dropOperation proposedDropOrperation: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSCollectionView.DropOperation>) -> NSDragOperation {
        return [.copy] // Not called if the drag destination is outside of my app
    }
}
```

## NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate

```
extension ImageViewController: NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate {
    func filePromiseProvider(_ filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider, fileNameForType fileType: String) -> String {
        // Return the promised filename.
        let metadata = filePromiseProvider.userInfo as! Metadata
        return metadata.fileName
    }
    
    func operationQueue(for filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider) -> OperationQueue {
        return workQueue
    }
    
    func filePromiseProvider(_ filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider, writePromiseTo url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        // Pull image over adb.
        let metadata = filePromiseProvider.userInfo as! Metadata
        ADB.executeAsync(args: "pull", metadata.path, url.path, callback: { (output) in
            completionHandler(nil)
        })
    }
}
```

**This is working so far but I need to make some improvements:**

How can I set the `NSDragOperation` to `.copy` in order to display the red circle with a plus while dragging? The function to validate the drop of the `NSCollectionViewDelegate` is only called when dragging inside of my application. When I provide a file `NSURL` as `NSPasteboardWriting` instead of the promise, the plus icon appears automatically. But as the file is not on my computer I have to use a promise instead.

Also I want to be able to drag the images directly into the photos app or at the dock icon so the image are automatically imported. Again, using an `NSURL` as `NSPasteboardWriting` is working but this is not possible for me. Can the photos app handle a file promise?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code NSFilesPromisePboardType/kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise  Use  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(4) forKey:@"NSDragManagerLogLevel"] to see types in dragging pasteboard in Photos.app

Comment: here you have file types for LOCAL drag https://imgur.com/a/v8O4ZFS

Comment: Why should I need NSFilesPromisePboardType/kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise? Im returning a 'NSFilePromiseProvider` instance in the pasteboardWriterForItemAt function.